# How to load category tree with category image

Tags: category, category-tree

I need load category image for the category tree. Currently I found a method to load category tree. But its not showing image of the category.

```
    public function getCategoryTree()
    {
        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category_api');
        $treeData = $model->tree();
        return $this->_sendJsonRespond('success', $treeData, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `tree` and`_nodeToArray` functions of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api` :

```
/**
 * Retrieve category tree
 *
 * @param int $parent
 * @param string|int $store
 * @return array
 */
public function tree($parentId = null, $store = null)
{
    if (is_null($parentId) && !is_null($store)) {
        $parentId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->_getStoreId($store))->getRootCategoryId();
    } elseif (is_null($parentId)) {
        $parentId = 1;
    }

    /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Tree */
    $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')
        ->load();

    $root = $tree->getNodeById($parentId);

    if($root && $root->getId() == 1) {
        $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root'));
    }

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('image');

    $tree->addCollectionData($collection, true);

    return $this->_nodeToArray($root);
}

/**
 * Convert node to array
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node
 * @return array
 */
protected function _nodeToArray(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
{
    // Only basic category data
    $result = array();
    $result['category_id'] = $node->getId();
    $result['parent_id']   = $node->getParentId();
    $result['name']        = $node->getName();
    $result['is_active']   = $node->getIsActive();
    $result['position']    = $node->getPosition();
    $result['level']       = $node->getLevel();
    $result['image']       = $node->getImage();
    $result['children']    = array();

    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
        $result['children'][] = $this->_nodeToArray($child);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Following your needs, I think that retrieving the collection of categories and formating it to your needs would be more advised.

Comment: what is $node and $parentId

Comment: I modified the post to make it fit to these two things. it was bad copy paste... sorry. parentId is the id of the category for wich you want to get the tree.

Comment: thanks. there's another issue in _nodeToArray  function call. can you please check again

Comment: I think you better overwrite Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api or retrieve collection and format it to your needs.

Comment: I'm new to magento. I can't understand what you mean

Comment: In that case, I advise you to do some tutorials about models and resources else, everything will look unaccessible...

Comment: Ah found it. Now its working. Thank you very much. Really, Thank you!!!

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf, while using this call `$tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')
        ->load();` more than one time simultaneously, its giving last one only on some servers, can you please suggest